# WCF data services service operation cannot materialize entity containing single quote

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

Try to use WCF data services service operation to get results from a SQL Stored proc. Overcame a few hurdles, such as the entity instead of complex type has to be used as return type, has to escape special chars in the query string etc., finally the service operation is get called and returns expected results in most cases, but NOT 100%.

The problem is that if a result contains a single quote, for example "O'Brien" in person's name, Chrome returns the result correctly, but context.Execute() yields nothing. Something is wrong when context.Exectue() materializes the result. How may I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() to the problematic properties in the service operation (WebGet) at server side. Also do the decode at client side.